# Rendering image from web source

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I've been working a while now on a project in which, I have to render image from a web repository.
I cannot find a way to render images from web via shiny if working within a Rmarkdown file.
Any idea ?

````
---
title: "Some Title"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup,include=FALSE}
##### Setup
# Setting base config
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,label_list=TRUE,comment = "",fig.align = "center")# This will make figures appears in the center of the document
# Loading all required lib
lapply(c("knitr",
         "stringr"
         ),
       require,
       character.only = TRUE)
# Setting some other confing
options(xtable.floating = FALSE,xtable.timestamp = "",xtable.comment = FALSE)
````

```
link = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
renderImage({list(src = link)})
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search, I came with this solution:

```
link = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
renderUI({tags$img(src = link)})
```

I'm sure why it works in Rmarkdown or otherwise, and could certainly be optimized, be whatever, it works. ^^